# How to run bash commands in gnome-pie app launcher

Tags: bash, eclipse, gnome-pie

I recently installed gnome pie app launcher and i was trying to edit the individual slices and run a bash command to open eclipse.

i'm running the more updated eclipse that i downloaded from eclipse's official site instead of the one from the Ubuntu repositories, so i can't type eclipse in the terminal to open eclipse.

There is the option of running a command but i pasted the command there but it doesn't display anything or run the application when i click on the slice, basically my commands involves changing into the directory where i installed eclipse and then running `./eclipse` (`cd /home/eclipse_directory; ./eclipse`) any suggestion on how to do this?

by the way i'm running Ubuntu 14.04 if that's an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `cd`. Use an absolute path to start `eclipse`:

```
/your_path_to_eclipse/eclipse
```

And if you have spaces in your path, so use **`"`**:

```
"/your_path_to_eclipse/eclipse"
```

### ;-)

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Test the command in a terminal.

Comment: woops!! one of my path directory has a space in it i had to put quotes around it, now it works. Thanks